# all things baseball

Tags: grammar

What does "all things baseball" mean in the following newspaper quote? How does the noun "baseball" function?
My guess is that "baseball" is used as a pseudo-adjective to modify "all things" from behind and that "all things baseball" means "all things about baseball. Am I all wrong?

“This guy [Shohei Otani] consumes all things baseball,” Eppler [Angels' GM] said. “There is not a lot else going on in his world but baseball and training. He does like to read a lot.”

Comment: Yep, the use of "all things" in that sense is something of an idiom meaning "everything about".

Answer (score -1):

You are correct.

*all things* is used an idiom meaning **everything to do with** or **everything about**

Answer (score -1):

**things**  [macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/thing?q=all%20things#thing__59) [plural]

> all of the aspects of a particular situation

Thus all things baseball, stamp collecting etc. One is consumed by and most knowledgeable in said subject.