# All things X adjective

Tags: adjectives

I am new to this site, but I know there is a similar question on it, it's just not quite the same.
What I mean by "all things X" could, for example, be like this: 
"He was interested in all things baseball." meaning that s/he is interested in everything that has something to do with baseball.
In this example there is a noun after "All things..."
Now, would it be proper for an adjective to replace the X?
I.e. s/he did all things possible but still couldn't find the solution.
Thank you in advance

Comment: I think the phrasing "every possible thing" would be more idiomatic.

Comment: 'He was knowledgeable in all things scientific' would work.

Comment: Related: "[What does “All things X” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252633)"  (I don't know if you saw it already; I assume from your choice of example that you have seen "[all things baseball](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/421931)")

Comment: @NigelJ: Yes, but it is really a somewhat high-falutin / poetic alternative to the more natural form today: *'He was knowledgeable in **everything** scientific'.* (Or maybe *'He **knew all about** everything scientific'.*)